# convert jpeg/png to tiff in java

Tags: image-processing, batik

I am using batik library for image conversion , I need to convert jpeg/png to tiff format.
Can anyone help me on how to do the conversion using batik (preferable) , because i am using the same library for other SVG conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do PNG - > SVG - > TIFF conversion.

This link should point you in the right direction: 
 http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html

check the "Examples of using the rasterizer task" section.

Hope this helps.